# Countdown timer in a static block with values from admin config

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets

I want to create a widget/static block with a countdown to the next shipment.

The shipment times should be changeable from the admin config, so I assume using PHP or PHTML are my options. (even though you can put JS code directly in a block, I believe it is not possible to call the values from config that way)

How do I make my static block execute a PHP code?

**Edit**

This is what I have:

`app\design\frontend\default\default\template\test.phtml`

```
<?php

echo "test";
```

`Content of my static block:`

```
{{block type="core/template" template="test.phtml"}}
```

The block doesn't display anything, what am I missing?

Comment: where did you displayed your static block?

Comment: On the home page

Comment: worked, so silly of me to not try to flush cache first. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display system config value in static block you can use this code directly in static block -

```
{{config path="your_section/group/field"}}
```

Or if you want to execute a php code in static block then the best way is to add your php code in  a phtml file and then call that phtml file in static block using

```
{{block type="your_module/your_block" template="your_template_path.phtml"}}
```

Comment: A dumb question perhaps, but if my `phtml` file path is `app\design\frontend\default\default\template\test.phtml` how much of it do I have to put in the "template="your_template_path.phtml"?

Comment: in template the value you put is the path of your file after `template/` directory, so in your case it will be only `test.phtml`

Comment: what do I replace the "your_module" and "your_block" with?

Comment: if you have your custom module and block then your should add your module and block name here otherwise you can add `core/template`

Comment: Please check my edit